# XKB Error: Couldn't lookup keysym Symbol interpretation ignored

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, keyboard-layout, xkb

I have someone's XKB file binding `Caps` + `uhjk` to arrows (here is the file https://gist.github.com/AlexP11223/945e24fdc07ae8b093ef939b46d30b64 with diff from the original). Now I am trying to bind `Caps` + `iopl` to `Home`, `End`, `Page Up`, `Page Down` and I get `Error: Couldn't lookup keysym Symbol interpretation ignored`  when adding

```
    interpret osfHome {
        repeat= True;
        action = RedirectKey(keycode=<HOME>, clearmodifiers=Lock);
    };
```

even though a very similar `interpret` worked fine above

```
    interpret osfLeft {
        repeat= True;
        action = RedirectKey(keycode=<LEFT>, clearmodifiers=Lock);
    };
```

Here is the file with diff from the `uhjk` file and all errors (standard and all warnings). https://gist.github.com/AlexP11223/2e7407bd002440fa4f0b1433a90a15af

Comment: Have you tried using [Xmodmap](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Xmodmap)?

Comment: How much free disk space have you got? Low disk space might be causing the issue as well.

Comment: Try using `KP_Home` instead of home (KP stands for keypad AFAIK)

Comment: Also according to [this](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=54015) setting the tmp directory permissions to 777 might solve your issue. Which distro are you using?

Comment: @SirMuffington Ubuntu 19.10. xmodmap doesn't work well in some cases. https://www.reddit.com/r/linuxquestions/comments/ci12wi/any_reliable_way_to_use_caps_lock_hjkl_as_arrow/

Comment: @SirMuffington I get syntax error with `RedirectKey(keycode=<KP_Home>, clearmodifiers=Lock)`, and the same errors as before for `KP_Home` without `< >`. `<HOME>` is defined at the beginning of the file, so it should work.

Comment: `/tmp` is 777 already (`drwxrwxrwt`) and I have lots of space.

Comment: I'm afraid I can't help you more that. Hopefully someone else helps ya out.